# Include Next.js app bundles in main html files

Tags: reactjs, laravel, deployment, next.js

I am converting React client-side rendering to SSR using Next.js but unable to load bundled files in my main view file.
These are not working on my end.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/bundles/server-side-components/out/_next/static/css/*.css" />
<link rel="preload" href="/js/bundles/server-side-components/out/_next/static/chunks/*.js" as="script" />
<link rel="preload" href="/js/bundles/server-side-components/out/_next/static/chunks/pages/*.js" as="script" />
```

Background:

1. I am using laravel and frontend React.js.
2. In laravel view (blade file). I have included react bundle file like this.
3. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bundles/SocialApp/dist/main.bundle.js?v=xxxx.xxx" async></script>`
4. Everything is working fine.
5. For performance, I wanted to move some components to Server-Side Rendering with Next.js.
6. I have removed the specific routes from react and moved these components to Next.js directory *Pages* folder. For Exmaple, If I wanted to move */example* route to SSR then, I have created a file with the same name (example.js) into *pages* directory of next.js and compiled the code.
7. If I start next.js server separately, like `http://localhost:3000/example`. Server-Side rendering working perfectly fine. but I don't want to start next.js server separately and wanted to include build files into my main directory like I am doing with react bundles.
8. How can I achieve my goal?